# Div with width 100% containing long text takes full window width inplace of full free space width

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple webpage here: https://jsfiddle.net/enxgz2Lm/1/

It is divided to a `side menu` and a `tasks container`.

The `tasks container` contains a `row container` which is devided to `checkbox`, `title` on the left-hand side and `details` to the right-hand side.

My question is about the `title` element.

This element is editable (using contenteditable="true"), I want it to be like that and not use `input` tag for a reason. I want it to take 100% of the free space, if the text is longer than the free space it should display a part of the text filling the free space and hide the rest (without breaking into new lines).

As you can see in the webpage I provided, I was able to do what I needed but the problem is that I can't figure out how to keep the width of the `title` to **100% of the free space**.

**PS: If you uncomment the CSS line *width: 470px* you can see how the webpage should look like approximately**

Comment: Please include all the code in the question. Don't just link to something. See [mre] for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `.side-menu-container { flex: none; }` (or `min-with:150px`).
Second, add `.tasks-contianer { flex: auto; }` instead of `width: 100%;` And to prevent stretching, you need to add `.tasks-contianer { min-width: 0; }` (or `overflow: hidden`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.side-menu-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  flex: none;
}

.tasks-contianer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #161A1F;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

.task-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.checkbox-container {
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.details-container {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.title-container {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.title-container p {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis; /* optional */
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu-container">
  <p>Category1</p>
  <p>Category2</p>
  <p>Category3</p>
</div>
<div class="tasks-contianer">
  <div class="task-container">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="title-container" contenteditable="true"><p>veryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpaceveryLongTextWithNoSpace
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="details-container">
      <p>details</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks brother, you saved me lots of time xD

Comment: Glad to help 